# TCP delivery and processing gurantees and exactly once guarantee in event / streaming based systems

Tags: apache-kafka, tcp, streaming, publish-subscribe

To the best of my knowledge, TCP provides **at least once delivery** (retransmission until an ACK), and **exactly once processing at the receiver** (duplicated packets are going to be just ignored and only one copy will be delivered to the app. ), if this is true why application layer messaging systems  (e.g., Kafka ) and streaming systems (e.g., Spark, ) would require their own application  level protocols to provide exactly once processing guarantees, why not just relying on TCP for one time delivery and/or processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reliability guarantees of TCP only cover data delivery between systems and not data delivery between applications. The recipient system sends an ACK back if the data were received by the OS and put into the receive buffer of the socket. This means the ACK might be send before the application reads and processes the data. To cover guarantees about reading and processing the data by the application some kind of ACK is therefore needed inside the application protocol.

Comment: So the app level ack is needed to guarantee that the message has been processed by the application it is kind of excatly once processing by the app. On the other hand, does TCP guarantee exactly once delivery to the socket buffer of the app, no need for extra work at the app level to ensure exactly once delivery to the app?

Comment: @MazenEzzeddine: TCP guarantees that the bytes are received in the same order as sent and that there are no additional data (like duplicates). But TCP has no idea of the meaning of the data, i.e. if the same application level message is actually send twice than TCP will dutifully deliver it twice. Now assume that a server crashed or got disconnected after the data were processed but before the app-level ACK was sent. The client does not know the current state of processing then and might deliver the same message data again. Thus it is useful to control such re-delivery also at the application.